# Pandas DataFrame won't pivot. Says duplicate indices

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

So basically I have 3 columns in my dataframe as follows:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 158143 entries, 0 to 203270
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count   Dtype         
---  ------         --------------   -----         
 0   users          158143 non-null  int64         
 1   dates          158143 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 2   medium_of_ans  158143 non-null  object
```

And I want it to be reshaped such that each entry in medium_of_ans value has a separate column and dates as row indices with users of a particular answer medium on a particular date resides in the junction of that row and column. In pandas similar functionality can be achieved by pivoting the dataframe although I am not able to achieve that as following attempt:

```
df.pivot(columns= 'medium_of_ans', index = 'dates', values = 'users')
```

throws this error:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

And I'm not sure why as a dataframe to be pivoted will obviously have duplicates in indices. That's why it is being pivoted. Resetting dataframe index as follows:

```
df.reset_index().pivot(columns= 'medium_of_ans', index = 'dates', values = 'users')
```

does not help either and error persists.

Comment: You need some sort of aggregation for duplicate records.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/6361531

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicates not just by the index, `dates`, but by the combination of index and column together, the combined `dates` and `medium_of_ans`.

You can find these duplicates with something like this:

```py
counts = df.groupby(['dates', 'medium_of_ans']).size().reset_index(name='n')
duplicates = counts[counts['n'] > 1]
```

If you want to combine the duplicates, for example by taking the mean of `users` for the cell, then you can use [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).

```py
df.pivot_table(columns='medium_of_ans', index='dates', values='users', aggfunc='mean')
```

Taking the mean is the default, but I have added the explicit parameter for clarity.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for. Though sum is the method for me